# Ghost Login failed for MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server

A bit in the background, I have two servers one is for the web application, and the other is a database server containing MSSQL.

I keep getting the message 'Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database '*****' [CLIENT: ]

We make connections with IP/User so we do not login like this; this happens practically to all databases.

The client local machine makes it sound it comes from the current server (MSSQL Server)

disabling the application that uses this specific database does not help; there are still logs coming it.

It's about 600 to 800.000 logs.

Does anyone have an idea how to figure out where this is coming from?